Как правильно записать лекало регулярного выражения для плагина Ruby ELK 7.17.0 для захвата IPv4-адреса в любом месте любой входной строки?
Здесь есть примеры, но с ними не срабатывает.
Я беру любое выражение для поиска совпадений в строке из интернета и делаю так: /(^(выражение))|(выражение)|((выражение)$)|(^(выражение)$)/, но оно не захватывает адрес в строке, если он стоит в конце строки, причём в тренажёрах серверных выражений всё работает. Как записать корректное выражение? Видел, что ещё некоторые вместо $ ставят \z - строгий конец строки, но как корректно захватывать именно начало или конец в этом плагине пока не понимаю.

Если в любом месте, то не нужно использовать якоря начала и конца строки совсем.

/\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|\d{1,2})\b/

Проверено на https://rubular.com/. "\b" в начале и в конце можно убрать при необходимости.

Спасибо! Действительно, исправил выражение на Ваше и стал использовать функцию gsub, а не sub, и всё заработало.
